# how to convert a nanotime to character?

Tags: r, data.table, nanotime

Consider this simple example

```
DT <- data.table::data.table(mytime =  c(nanotime('2011-12-05 08:30:00.000',format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E9S",  tz ="GMT"),
                         nanotime('2011-12-05 08:30:00.100',format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E9S",  tz ="GMT"),
                         nanotime('2011-12-05 08:30:00.825',format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E9S",  tz ="GMT")))
#convert the timestamp to string
DT[, mytime_character := strftime(mytime, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3')]

> DT
                                mytime        mytime_character
1: 2011-12-05T08:30:00.000000000+00:00 2011-12-05 03:30:00.000
2: 2011-12-05T08:30:00.100000000+00:00 2011-12-05 03:30:00.099
3: 2011-12-05T08:30:00.825000000+00:00 2011-12-05 03:30:00.825
```

As you can see, converting the `nanotime` timestamp to `character` (using `strftime`) creates a wrong millisecond part for the second timestamp: `.099` instead of `.100`

Unfortunately, I need to convert my timestamps to string so that they can be ingested by other programming languages.

Is there a way to convert the timestamps properly to character without precision loss?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are having an elementary misunderstanding here.

We use `nanotime` *because the standard time formats in R only have (not-quite) microsecond resolution*.  So you, by using `strftime()` on it, are doing it wrong.

But `nanotime`, being a proper package, *of course* has a `format()` method:

```
R> DT <- data.table::data.table(mt = c(nanotime('2011-12-05 08:30:00.000',format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E9S",  tz ="GMT"),
+                                      nanotime('2011-12-05 08:30:00.100',format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E9S",  tz ="GMT"),
+                                      nanotime('2011-12-05 08:30:00.825',format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E9S",  tz ="GMT")))
R> 
R> DT[, fmt := format(mt)]
R> DT[]
                                    mt                                 fmt
1: 2011-12-05T08:30:00.000000000+00:00 2011-12-05T08:30:00.000000000+00:00
2: 2011-12-05T08:30:00.100000000+00:00 2011-12-05T08:30:00.100000000+00:00
3: 2011-12-05T08:30:00.825000000+00:00 2011-12-05T08:30:00.825000000+00:00
R>
```

Comment: thanks Dirk again for your time. The reason I try to use `nanotime` is that it does not create rounding errors for timestamps like `'2011-12-05 08:30:00.100`. This does not happen in Pandas, for instance. My understanding is that `nanotime` manages that thanks to its microsecond precision, although I might be wrong. It would be nice to have functions to extract the other components (year, day, hour, minute, etc) from the nanotime timestamp without having to convert to posixct. Again, maybe I am foolish here. Thanks!

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ The point of Dirk's answer is that you should use the `format` method instead of converting to posixct. You want the year? `format(x, format = "%Y")`. You want the day? `format(x, format = "%d")`. No other functions are needed. You use `strftime`? You implicitly convert to posix and lose the advantages of nanotime.

Comment: ha!!! I didnt get that! thanks for clarifying. this is pretty useful. Also, it does seem `nanotime` plays well with `tibbles`

Comment: Not sure it does. First line of my first (ie in the other question) answer to you told you explicitly `data.table` does. It is what I use.  If you read "use tibble" into that, you have a problem.  Maybe `tibble` works, maybe it doesn't.  Either way I (co-)wrote `nanotime` and I can assure you I do not use `tibble` with it.

Comment: OK but when I print my tibble with a nanotime timestamp I get `<S4: nanotime> ` as the type. Isnt that what we want? Do you mean the computations will be affected if I use a tibble? I am asking this because making this wonderful package compatible with `tibbles` would be great (I use data.table or tibbles as needed)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel that makes me hope its OK because in https://github.com/eddelbuettel/nanotime/issues/31 even the priting of the nanotime was impossible

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works for you

```r
DT[, mytime_character := format(mytime)]
DT %>% str()

> DT %>% str()
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ mytime          :integer64 1323073800000000000 1323073800100000000 1323073800825000000 
 $ mytime_character: chr  "2011-12-05T08:30:00.000000000+00:00" "2011-12-05T08:30:00.100000000+00:00" "2011-12-05T08:30:00.825000000+00:00"
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```